# birdy.twitter.TwitterApiError: Unable to decode JSON response

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to analyse the twitter realtime data using Streaming API using OAuth 2.0

I am using birdy twitter API client [link](https://github.com/inueni/birdy)

```
from birdy.twitter import AppClient,StreamResponse

CONSUMER_KEY = 'B....c'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'l....A'

client = AppClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
access_token = client.get_access_token()
resource = client.stream.statuses.filter.post(track='twitter')
for data in resource.stream():
       print data
```

while executing,i get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "webapp/streams.py", line 23, in 
>       resource = client.stream.statuses.filter.post(track='twitter')
>     File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/twitter-livestream/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/birdy/twitter.py", line 86, in post
>       return self._client.request('POST', self._path, **params)
>
> File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/twitter-livestream/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/birdy/twitter.py", line 167, in request
>       return self.handle_response(method, response)
>
> File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/twitter-livestream/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/birdy/twitter.py", line 189, in handle_response
>       raise TwitterApiError('Unable to decode JSON response.', response=response, request_method=method)
>
> birdy.twitter.TwitterApiError: Unable to decode JSON response. (POST https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json)

Thanks in Advance ...:)

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using Python 3)

The following works for me...

```
from birdy.twitter import StreamClient

# insert your consumer key/secret, access token/secret
client = StreamClient("xx",
                    "xx",
                    "xx",
                    "xx")

response = client.stream.statuses.filter.post(track='twitter')
for data in response.stream():
    print (data)
```

Comment: More specifically, you're using AppClient, and I don't see any evidence that AppClient will work with the streaming methods.

Comment: thank you .... i got the result ...and i am having a doubt ... is it a correct way of using OAuth 2.0 or can it be done by using django allauth ..does it provide OAuth 2.0 ?

Comment: No, this method requires Oauth 1.0a

Comment: can u provide a link or tell the steps how to do it with OAuth 2.0 ?? it will be really helpful ??

Comment: There's no way to do this, the Twitter API does not support application-only authentication for streams.